# Using CSS to Get an Element Who Has a Certain Sibling

Tags: css

If I have this markup:

```
<label>Email Address:</label>
<input class="validation-failed" type="text"></input>
```

How do I select the label, *only* if the input has the class `.validation-failed`?

Comment: You can't. There's no previous sibling selector in CSS yet.

Comment: What @j08691 said. Also it's worth noting that in CSS level 4 selectors you can [determine the subject of a selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) by `!` mark as `!label + .validation-failed`. But none of web browsers have implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments there is no pure css solution,

There is a jQuery solution using the .prev() method, ref: https://api.jquery.com/prev/